Accessibility sort priority not working with TextField in Swiftui
I am trying to achieve particular sequence for voice over in SwiftUI screen.
Below is the code i tried :
@State private var inputValue: String = "Input Data value"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Text1")
                    .accessibilitySortPriority(3)
                
                Text("Text2")
                    .accessibilitySortPriority(1)
            }
            
            TextField("Enter Value", text:$inputValue)
                .accessibilitySortPriority(2)
            
        }
        .accessibilityElement(children: .combine)

Voice Over will always have sequence : Text1, Text2 and Enter Value.
It should have Text1, Enter Value and Text2.
Because priority for Enter Value = 2 and Text2 = 1
I also tried .contain but it is not working
    .accessibilityElement(children: .contain)


There is issue in Mac book Accessibility inspector. accessibilitySortPriority() works properly if same code is testes in real device

There is bug in Mac book Accessibility inspector. accessibilitySortPriority() works properly if same code is testes in real device
